# Why does flutter_hooks throw an error if I don't use SearchController?

Tags: flutter

First I hooked up `hooks_riverpod` which didn't recognize `useEffect`, then I hooked up `flutter_hooks` and it threw an error: Method not found: 'SearchController'.

**Error:**
.../Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_hooks-0.20.0/lib/src/search_controller.dart:21:22: Error: Method not found: 'SearchController'.
final controller = SearchController();

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:riverpod_firebase_register_crud_app/ui/utils/lables.dart';

import '../root.dart';

class SplashPage extends HookWidget {
  const SplashPage({super.key});

  static const String route = '/splash';

  void startController() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    useEffect(() {
      startController();
      if (Navigator.canPop(context)) {
        Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          Root.route,
          (route) => false,
        );
      }
      return null; // Returning null to indicate no cleanup is needed
    }, const []);

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primaryContainer,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.favorite,
              size: 80,
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            Text(
              Labels.appName,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge!.copyWith(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To temporarily work around this issue, you can comment out `search_controller.dart` in `flutter_hooks>lib>src>hooks.dart`

Answer (score 2):

Not the best solution though Downgrade works

Use this for now:  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.6